# Magento 2 Product Page Not Loading Correctly

Tags: magento2, product

New to Magento 2 and just did a **fresh install** and must have set something wrong, perhaps in the rewrite url.

I have a `single subcategory` called **Test** and `1 product` called **product1**.

This product is in the Test category and shows up fine on the nav and within the catalog page, but is blank when I select the product detail page.

**url** `www.domain.com/product1.html`

When I manually change the **url** to `www.domain.com/test/product1.html` it works fine.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Configuration -> Web -> Base URL's look like this:

- **Base URL** `www.domain.com`
- **Base Link URL** `www.domain.com`
- **Base URL for Static View Files** `Blank`
- **Base URL for User Media Files** `Blank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base URL: www.domain.com/Test

Base Link URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}